# for loop in bash using mkvmerge

Tags: linux, bash

I have a couple of videos with its correspondings .srt files. I'm trying to merge them using a loop, but I'm stuck. This piece of code doesn't work:

```
for i in *".avi"
do
    mkvmerge -o "$i.mkv"\
    *$i".avi" \
    *$i".esp.srt"

done
```

Instead, if I use this piece of code:

```
for i in *".avi"
do
    mkvmerge -o "$i.mkv"\
    *".avi" \
    *".esp.srt"

done
```

It merges all the existing files putting correct names to the new files created.

But I want only to merge "i.avi"+"i.srt"-->"i.mkv" for all the avi files in the folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use glob pattern in merge command. Try this:

```
for i in *.avi
do
    i="${i%.avi}"
    mkvmerge -o "$i.mkv" "$i.avi" "$i.esp.srt"
done
```

Comment: Put `echo mkvmerge -o "$i.mkv" "$i.avi" "$i.esp.srt"` inside loop and see what it prints.

Comment: It says (translate from Spanish): Error: The file "1.avi.avi" could not be opened for reading: open file error

Comment: You need to trim the `.avi` extension from `i` prior to the call to mkvmerge: `i=${i%.avi}`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner: Let me add it to my answer.

Comment: And how can I do it if the files have different names? For example: file1.avi and whatever_file1.srt

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was looking for is:

```
for i in *".avi"
do
    mkvmerge -o "${i%%".avi"}.mkv"\
    "$i" \
    "${i%%".avi"}.esp.srt"

done
```

For sure, that it can be improved! 
Anyway, thanks to anubhava for his help with the echo command which gave me a way to solve it!

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily complex -- you only need the outer quotes, not the inner ones.

Comment: Above @chepner gave me the answer to do it!

Comment: @david_doji: You can see my answer how to simplify this loop.

Comment: @david_doji, yes, and chepner's comment doesn't have the unnecessary inner quotes. It's simpler than what you're using here.

Answer (score -1):

Try building your loop logic first and then adding the tasks you want to complete.

```
DATADIR="/data/video"
for i in $(ls $DATADIR/*.avi); do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: No. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls (entries #1 and #14).

Comment: Did you follow the links? It's more than just quotes at issue.